microros does not connect to ROS2 humble
I want to build a ros2 robot with microros on esp32. I was trying the guide from here but i don't see the topics in the topic list.
I have also tried changing the ROS_DOMAIN_ID to 0 as stated here but the results are same.
I wanted to share the complete log but the character limit exceeds. Please help, if any one require any information please leave a comment I will share.
Thanks
